# How can I debug my background image in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, animation

I'm trying to write a program in which I animate a mathematical function. I want to use a background image, though. I've tried it, and the program starts well, but soon it looses track of the image and it gets all messed up. How can I fix that issue?

I've tried re-sizing the image in real time along with the x and y limits, but still it keeps getting messy. I'm using matplotlib and numpy.

This image is while the program is working:

[image]

However, in this one the program is bugged:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np

#[...]

def animate(data): #refresh data shown
    x,y = data
    xdata.append(x)
    ydata.append(y)
    xmin,xmax = ax.get_xlim()

    if x >= xmax:
        ax.set_xlim(xmin,2*xmax)
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()


    line.set_data(xdata,ydata)
    return line


img = plt.imread("myimage.jpg")
ax.imshow(img, extent=[0, ax.get_xlim()[-1], ax.get_ylim()[0], ax.get_ylim()[-1]]) 

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,data_gen,blit=True,interval=10,repeat = False)
plt.show()
```

(I've tried to upload images to this question but until now I was not able to do it)

Comment: Actually it should work when using blit=True. One cannot find out why it doesn't without runnable code. For blit=False, the problem could be best solved by either adding the image in axes coordinates, instead of data coordinates, or by placing it in a different axes in the background.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved! For some reason, it worked when I changed the ylimits. Perhaps the image was not able to resize into different scales(?). Modifications:

```
if x >= xmax:
    ax.set_xlim(xmin,2*xmax)
    ax.set_ylim(-1.5*xmax,1.5*xmax)
    ax.figure.canvas.draw()
```

[image: screenshot of program debugged, running smoothly]